# How to change the color of the CheckMark in WPF CheckBox control?

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

I have a custom template checkbox that I am implementing using a viewbox (using a viewbox to allow for simple scaling), and I can't figure out how to change out what is displayed when the checkbox is checked/unchecked.

I would like for the checkmark to be red when checked (not the final look, just want to see it working).

**My Checkbox style:**

```
<Style x:Key="KioskCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource FontFamilyLight}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource KioskNormalFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource brshSystemTextColor}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">

                        <!--<Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                 Stretch="Fill" 
                                 Height="30"   
                                 Width="30" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                            <Grid Height="200" Width="200">
                                <Ellipse  
                                Fill="Transparent"
                                StrokeThickness="15" 
                                Stroke="{StaticResource brshSystemTextColor}"/>
                                <Path 
                                Stroke="{StaticResource brshSecondaryColor}"
                                Fill="Transparent" 
                                Stretch="None"
                                StrokeThickness="20"
                                Data="M 30,100 L 80,140 L 160,60" Margin="0,0,2,2"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Viewbox>-->
                        <ContentControl>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Stretch="Fill" 
                                Height="30"   
                                Width="30" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                                <Grid Height="200" Width="200">
                                    <Ellipse  
                                        Fill="Transparent"
                                        StrokeThickness="15" 
                                        Stroke="{StaticResource brshSystemTextColor}"/>
                                    <Path 
                                        Stroke="{StaticResource brshSecondaryColor}"
                                        Fill="Transparent" 
                                        Stretch="None"
                                        StrokeThickness="20"
                                        Data="M 30,100 L 80,140 L 160,60" Margin="0,0,2,2"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Viewbox>
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ContentControl> 
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">

                            <!-- Running into problems here. -->

                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">

                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go for the original template ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752319.aspx)). This is the part where the color is defined:

```
<Path Visibility="Collapsed"
      Width="7"
      Height="7"
      x:Name="CheckMark"
      SnapsToDevicePixels="False"
      StrokeThickness="2"
      Data="M 0 0 L 7 7 M 0 7 L 7 0">
  <Path.Stroke>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource GlyphColor}" />
  </Path.Stroke>
</Path>
```

Sorry, sorry and sorry again... I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
  <Grid>
    <Path x:Name="Equis"
          Opacity="0"
          Stroke="Red"
          Fill="Red"
          Stretch="UniformToFill"
          StrokeThickness="20"
          Data="M 30,100 L 80,140 L 160,60"
          Margin="0,0,2,2" />
    <ContentPresenter Margin="4"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" />
  </Grid>
  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
             Value="true">
      <Setter TargetName="Equis"
              Property="Opacity"
              Value="1" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
             Value="false">
      <Setter TargetName="Equis"
              Property="Opacity"
              Value="0" />
    </Trigger>
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but can you throw that into **<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">  </Trigger>** and post it so that I can get a better idea of what you are telling me?

Comment: AGoodDisplayName: Well, you said "I would like for the check mark to be red when checked" the default template uses the code I posted to draw the check mark. Blam: I guess the "Collapsed" gets modified to "Visible", when the value for the checkbox is true.

Comment: @NestroArturo, sorry for the late response. I didn't see the your edit until today. Funny thing too, I figured this out on my own yesterday doing exactly what you are showing in your example, so thanks for the answer.

Comment: cool solution, but for me not every click is respected after applying this kind of style - anyone else having this issue?