# WPF Change colour of checkmark in Listboxitem with ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, listboxitem, checkedlistbox

Any WPF experts out there who can show me how to modify my styles in order to change the  the colour of the checkmark of a Checkbox contained in a ListBoxItem. So far I have the following which is cobbled together from MahApps styling:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroListBox}" x:Key="CheckBoxList" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            CornerRadius="3">
                    <ScrollViewer>
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox   IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" 
                            Content="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Border"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="5, 0, 0, 0" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource AccentSelectedColorBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource AccentColor3}" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource GrayBrush5}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource GrayBrush5}" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource AccentSelectedColorBrush}" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource AccentSelectedColorBrush}" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource AccentColor3}" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Regards
Alan

Comment: 1 Go to youtube and play ghostbusters soundtrack. 2 Go to microsoft.com and search for checkbox style. 3 Copy paste the style and change the color of path which represents the tick.  4 Pronounce yourself an expert if you done before soundtrack ended

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can refer to the answer to this question...i.e defining own template for checkbox:
[How to change the color of the CheckMark in WPF CheckBox control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727140/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-checkmark-in-wpf-checkbox-control)