# How do I change the colour of a WPF Checkbox tick?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I would like to change the colour of the tick in my WPF `CheckBox` from black to white. I have tried to do this in the `CheckBox`declaration as such:

```
<CheckBox Background="black" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="#262626"/>
```

The background and border successfully change, but not the tick itself.

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727140/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-checkmark-in-wpf-checkbox-control/9727232

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could copy the entire checkbox style from the MSDN server but because its very confusing to work with in the beginning of any WPF carreer, I compiled the (in my opinion) neccessary bits into one style thats a little easier to understand:

[image]

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF262E34"/>
    <!--                           your color here -->
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="HotPink"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Width="15" Height="15">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="1" Visibility="Collapsed" Name="nullBlock"/>
                            <Path Stretch="Uniform" Width="15" Height="10" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Name="eliCheck" Data="F1 M 9.97498,1.22334L 4.6983,9.09834L 4.52164,9.09834L 0,5.19331L 1.27664,3.52165L 4.255,6.08833L 8.33331,1.52588e-005L 9.97498,1.22334 Z " Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF9C9E9F" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="eliCheck" Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="eliCheck" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter TargetName="nullBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

[image]

Comment: How would you make the tick normal how it usually is?

Comment: you would adjust this path to match your requirements:
               <Path Width="15" Height="10"  Stroke="HotPink" StrokeThickness="3" Name="eliCheck" Data="M 2,4 C 2,4 3,5 5,13 C 5,13 5,3 12,0" Visibility="Collapsed"/>

Comment: Great solution, but keep in mind that the `IsChecked` property is nullable, and using this solution will not show it visually.

Comment: @radoczsanyi_ i rarely ever use the null-state but its a good point, I edited the style to include your suggestion

Answer (score 3):

The `CheckBox` control has various visual states with different colors for background, border and option mark glyph. You can refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/checkbox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) for the required parts and visual states.

If you want to edit the colors, you have to change the default style and control template. You can extract it [using Blend or Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825030/how-to-extract-default-control-template-in-visual-studio). Below is the default template. What you need to do is copy these resources to a resource dictionary in scope, e.g. the application resources and adapt the `SolidColorBursh`es.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFF3F9FF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF5593FF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFD9ECFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF3C77DD"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFE6E6E6"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFBCBCBC"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph" Color="#FF707070"/>

<Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
   <Setter Property="Control.Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate>
            <Rectangle Margin="2"
                       SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                       Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"
                       StrokeDashArray="1 2"
                       StrokeThickness="1" />
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="OptionMarkFocusVisual">
   <Setter Property="Control.Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate>
            <Rectangle Margin="14,0,0,0"
                       SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                       Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"
                       StrokeDashArray="1 2"
                       StrokeThickness="1" />
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
   <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
           Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}" />
   <Setter Property="Background"
           Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Background}" />
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
           Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Border}" />
   <Setter Property="Foreground"
           Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
           Value="1" />
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Grid x:Name="templateRoot"
                  Background="Transparent"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <Border x:Name="checkBoxBorder"
                       Margin="1"
                       HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                       VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                       Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                       BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                       BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                  <Grid x:Name="markGrid">
                     <Path x:Name="optionMark"
                           Margin="1"
                           Data="F1 M 9.97498,1.22334L 4.6983,9.09834L 4.52164,9.09834L 0,5.19331L 1.27664,3.52165L 4.255,6.08833L 8.33331,1.52588e-005L 9.97498,1.22334 Z "
                           Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}"
                           Opacity="0"
                           Stretch="None" />
                     <Rectangle x:Name="indeterminateMark"
                                Margin="2"
                                Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}"
                                Opacity="0" />
                  </Grid>
               </Border>
               <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                 Grid.Column="1"
                                 Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                 VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                 Focusable="False"
                                 RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                 SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="HasContent"
                        Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
                          Value="{StaticResource OptionMarkFocusVisual}" />
                  <Setter Property="Padding"
                          Value="4,-1,0,0" />
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                        Value="true">
                  <Setter TargetName="checkBoxBorder"
                          Property="Background"
                          Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Background}" />
                  <Setter TargetName="checkBoxBorder"
                          Property="BorderBrush"
                          Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Border}" />
                  <Setter TargetName="optionMark"
                          Property="Fill"
                          Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}" />
                  <Setter TargetName="indeterminateMark"
                          Property="Fill"
                          Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}" />
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                        Value="false">
                  <Setter TargetName="checkBoxBorder"
                          Property="Background"
                          Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Background}" />
                  <Setter TargetName="checkBoxBorder"
                          Property="BorderBrush"
                          Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Border}" />
                  <Setter TargetName="optionMark"
                          Property="Fill"
                          Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}" />
                  <Setter TargetName="indeterminateMark"
                          Property="Fill"
                          Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}" />
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                        Value="true">
                  <Setter TargetName="checkBoxBorder"
                          Property="Background"
                          Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Background}" />
                  <Setter TargetName="checkBoxBorder"
                          Property="BorderBrush"
                          Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Border}" />
                  <Setter TargetName="optionMark"
                          Property="Fill"
                          Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}" />
                  <Setter TargetName="indeterminateMark"
                          Property="Fill"
                          Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}" />
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                        Value="true">
                  <Setter TargetName="optionMark"
                          Property="Opacity"
                          Value="1" />
                  <Setter TargetName="indeterminateMark"
                          Property="Opacity"
                          Value="0" />
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                        Value="{x:Null}">
                  <Setter TargetName="optionMark"
                          Property="Opacity"
                          Value="0" />
                  <Setter TargetName="indeterminateMark"
                          Property="Opacity"
                          Value="1" />
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Since there are different colors for the *Static*, *MouseOver*, *Pressed* and *Disabled* states, you might have to derive a small color palette from your background, border and foreground colors.

In order to use the adapted check box style, you can reference it explicitly by key:

```
<CheckBox Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle}" />
```

You can also define an implicit style like below after the other resources, so the style will automatically be applied to all `CheckBox`es in scope of the containing resource dictionary.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle}"/>
```

In this case you do not reference the style explicitly anymore.

```
<CheckBox />
```

Comment: thats the more detailed answer which is taechnically **better** however i am afraid this might "scare" beginners